# How to get indices of lists in a list of lists in Python?

Tags: list, indices

I have a list of lists (named my_list) comprising lists of different lengths. I want to get the indices of lists with length 1, indices of lists with length 2, and so on. I tried the following, but in vain.

```
print([i for i, j in enumerate(my_list) if len([x for x in my_list if len(x) == 1]) in j][0])
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried nested for loops:

```
for list in my_list:
    if len(list) == 1:
        print(my_list.index(list))
```

Comment: I did.  I get an error.

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: You can modify this code by getting the sizes of all the lists and save them with the indices of the lists.

Comment: I made a sample code:

Comment: lists = []

list1 = {1, 2, 3}
list2 = {4, 6, 8, 2}
list3 = {1}

lists.append(list1)
lists.append(list2)
lists.append(list3)

for list in lists:
    if len(list) == 1:
        print(lists.index(list))

Comment: @ NGB -- what modifications did you use?